# Bullet instantiation angle is wrong when the player rotates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I created a projectile bullet effect with 3 different instantiation positions. It works perfectly while the player is facing right. But when facing left the angle of the bullet instantiation goes astray. Any help is appreciated.

Screenshot of when the player is turning right.

[image]

Screenshot of when the player is turning left.

[image]

The code of the player.

```
private IEnumerator FireContinuously()
{
    while (true)
    {
        GameObject laser02 = Instantiate(bullet01, firePoint2.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 10)));
        laser02.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = laser02.transform.right * projectileSpeed * direction;
        GameObject laser03 = Instantiate(bullet02, firePoint.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)));
        laser03.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = laser03.transform.right * projectileSpeed * direction;
        GameObject laser04 = Instantiate(bullet03, firePoint3.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 345)));
        laser04.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = laser04.transform.right * projectileSpeed * direction;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(projectileFiringPeriod);
    }
}

public void Flipsprite()
{    
    bool playerhashorizontalspeed = Mathf.Abs(myRigidBody.velocity.x) > 0;

    if (playerhashorizontalspeed)
    {        
        direction = Mathf.Sign(myRigidBody.velocity.x);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(direction, 1f);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using hardcoded angles `10` and `345` regardless the direction you are looking.

Then using e.g. `laser02.right` always returns the same `Vector3` only that you negate it. That results in an incorrect direction. It is the direction you get if you compare the images.

What you rather want is to negate also the angle by which you rotated the bullets.

```
private IEnumerator FireContinuously()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var laser02 = Instantiate(bullet01, firePoint2.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 10 * direction)));
        laser02.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = laser02.transform.right * projectileSpeed * direction;

        var laser03 = Instantiate(bullet02, firePoint.position, Quaternion.Identity)
        laser03.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = laser03.transform.right * projectileSpeed * direction;

        var laser04 = Instantiate(bullet03, firePoint3.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 345 * direction)));
        laser04.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = laser04.transform.right * projectileSpeed * direction;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(projectileFiringPeriod);
    }
}
```

---

And a little hint:

If you would rather make your prefabs of type

```
[SerializeField] private RigidBody2D bullet01;
[SerializeField] private RigidBody2D bullet02;
[SerializeField] private RigidBody2D bullet03;
```

then `Instantiate` would directly return the according `RigidBody2D` reference and you could get rid of the `GetComponent` calls:

```
private IEnumerator FireContinuously()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var laser02 = Instantiate(bullet01, firePoint2.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 10 * direction)));
        laser02.velocity = laser02.transform.right * projectileSpeed * direction;

        var laser03 = Instantiate(bullet02, firePoint.position, Quaternion.Identity)
        laser03.velocity = laser03.transform.right * projectileSpeed * direction;

        var laser04 = Instantiate(bullet03, firePoint3.position, Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, 345 * direction)));
        laser04.velocity = laser04.transform.right * projectileSpeed * direction;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(projectileFiringPeriod);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly @derHugo And thank you for this and the suggestion with Instantiating directly instead through Get Component.